# Figuring out whether a ring is a field

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Given a ring, how do you test whether it is a field? What properties would you look at?

Comment: Commutative, unitary and every non-zero element must be invertible.

Comment: If it's finite, by Wedderburn's theorem you don't need to check commutative.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you asking what is one definition of a field, or, instead, are you asking for various (practical?) tests to verify that a ring is a field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean a commutative ring with a multiplicative unit. There are a few ways you can check that such a ring is a field.

- (perhaps the most common) Find an explicit inversion operation, i.e. a function $i : F \to F$ such that $x \cdot i(x) = 1$ for every nonzero $x\in F$.
- If the ring is finite, you need only prove it has no zero divisors, because this means that multiplication by nonzero constants is injective, which in the finite case means that it is surjective (so bijective, so has an inverse).
- Alternatively, prove that there are no nontrivial ideals. If every ideal is trivial then all the principal ideals, i.e. the sets $\{ xa : a \in F \}$, contain $1$ (or are zero). Hence every nonzero $x$ has some $a$ such that $xa = 1$, so $a$ is an inverse for $x$.

  - A related idea would be to prove that your ring is the quotient of some other ring by a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 3):

> A field is a nonzero commutative ring that contains a multiplicative
>   inverse for every nonzero element

This is from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29

Comment: And, based on the amount of information user gave us, this is the best answer.